# Dispatching actions from presenational components with regards to Container Component pattern?

Tags: reactjs, components, containers, react-redux

I have just started to explore the Container Component pattern. What I don't quite grasp yet is the concept of presentational component only being concerned with the visuals.

Does that mean that these component can't dispatch action that would change the redux state?

e.g

```
<MainContainer> 
  <ListComponent />
  <GraphComponent />
</MainContainer>
```

Say `<GraphComponent>` shows graphs based on a list in redux state. The `<ListComponent>` then modify this list in the redux state with buttons. Is this okay in the Container Component pattern?

Comment: Your container would know about redux; your components will not. They should be dumb and can be used by a parent component that manages the state by itself ot by a parent container that is bound to Redux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you're not supposed to dispatch actions in Components. In Container-Component pattern, you're supposed to pass a callback function from the container (`MainContainer` in your case) as props to `ListComponent`, that fires when the button is clicked and dispatch action (in container) as result.

Answer (score 1):

`Presentation (Dumb) components` are like 1st grade students, they have their unique appearance but their behavior and the content they put out is decided or taught by their parents.
Example: `<Button />`

```
export const Button = props => {
  <button type="button" onClick={props.onClick} />{props.text}</button>
}
```

Unique appearance: it's a button
Behavior: onClick
Content: text
Both onClick and text are provided by parent.

---

When they grow to 5th or 7th grade, they may start to have their own `state` and decide few of the things on their own.
Example: `<Input />`

```
class Input extends Component {
 constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
   value: ''
  }
 }

 handleChange = (e) => {
  this.setState({value: e.target.value});
 }

 render() {
  return (
   <input 
    type="text"
    value={this.state.value}
    onChange={this.handleChange}
    onFocus={this.props.onFocus}
   />
  );
 }
}
```

Unique appearance: it's an input
State: decides it own value.
Behavior: onFocus
onFocus provided by parent.

---

And when they become adults they may start to behave on their own and may not
need their parents guidance. They start to talk to the outer world (redux store)
on their own (now they are new Container components).
Example

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, [ownProps]) => {
 ...
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (state, [ownProps]) => {
 ...
}

const MyComponent = (props) => {
 return (
  <ChildComponent {...props} />
 );
}

connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MyComponent);
```

Decides its own behavior and content, may or may not need parent (read ownProps)

---

Presentational components may or may not need any behavior of their own,
they rely on their parents for that. But to talk (dispatch) to the outer 
world(store) they need to be big enough (Container components).

So the main thing to remember here is start small and decide as your component
grows whether it needs to be a presentational or container component.